# ionic change default font

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I know this question is asked and answered before in the links below. I want to change the default font without having to add to every css.

Things I have tried:

1. Changing the .tff, .eot, .woff, .svg file directly to merge my fonts and ionicons
2. Tried to implement the font by specifying it in html and css file (it works, but i want it to be default)
3. Overwrite the www/lib/ionic/fonts with open-sans font (the ionicons disappear)
4. When i use the first link (all formatting is gone, only left with text and buttons) I also tried placing the font-face on top and bottom in scss/ionic.app.scss

Please help! The answers i have seen are instructions but no explanation how it works. I don't know how "ionic setup sass" works/what it does. How gulp plays a part in this.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-change-the-font-of-all-texts-in-ionic/30459

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/change-font-family-and-use-ionicons-icons/26729

Comment: For ionic 4, the solution is different, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223811/323900

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Import all the **`font files`** in to your app.

Example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato-Light';
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Light.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Lato-Light.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Lato-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

If you want this font in entire app ,Just give like this

```
* {
    font-family: 'Lato-Light' !important;
}
```

If you have any doubt.Please let me know.Thanks

Comment: A problem with this approach is that my fontawesome icons don't work because of the !important directive.

Comment: what worked for me was to leave out !important and to modify the $font-family-sans-serif and $font-family-light-sans-serif variables in _variables.scss so that my font is first on the list.

Answer (score 35):

The correct solution for Ionic 2 should be to change the `$font-family-base` [variable](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) and its friends. That's the way Ionic is made to do it. It gives you more control (like having different fonts per platform), and it avoids the `!important` keyword, which is always a good thing.

Using Ionic 3.3, go to your `variables.scss` and find the section "Shared variables". Add these lines:

```
$font-family-base: 'MyFont';
$font-family-ios-base: 'MyFont';
$font-family-md-base: 'MyFont';
$font-family-wp-base: 'MyFont';
```

Comment: Where did you put the font files ? & how did you import them?

Comment: I created a _fonts.scss that I import in variables.scss. The fonts themselves exist in the assets folder. The content of _fonts.css is generated by transfonter.org. This is not necessarily the right way, it's just a possible solution.

Answer (score 23):

#### For Ionic 4

There are global variables that are shared across components. `--ion-font-family` is one of them.
Add this in property under `:root` in `variables.scss`:

```
  :root {
      --ion-font-family: 'MyFont';
  }
```

Ionic 4 Docs: [Advanced Theming Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced#globals)

Answer (score 11):

You don't want to replace the icon font by the way, so you should use the CSS3 not() property

For example, in app.scss :

```
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);

  *:not(ion-icon) {
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif!important;
  }
```

Comment: Very useful when using ionicons or third parties. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For Ionic 2:
Download the fonts from fonts.google.com and paste it in your assets folder. Now in your scss file do the following:

```
@font-face {
font-family: MyFont;
src: url("../assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf");
}

body, span, button, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ion-item, ion-title {
font-family: 'MyFont' !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include your icons as `svg` format.

Here's a list with all the latest `ionicons`: https://github.com/Orlandster1998/ionicons-svg

Answer (score 0):

as stated above for me adding the following lines in `global.scss` file worked. It works also taking the `!important` out.
Initially it was not working as the url I put was incorrect. The url below is the right url if you have put your custom font inside a folder called `fonts` inside `assets` which you find in folder `src`.
In  my case I had made a mistake in the url initially and when I was pointing to `'/fonts/MonumentGrotesk-Mono.ttf'` it was not showing errors but showing Times New Roman font for the whole App. Then changing to the right url `'/assets/fonts/MonumentGrotesk-Mono.ttf'` worked brilliantly.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'MonumentGrotesk-Mono';
        src: url('/assets/fonts/MonumentGrotesk-Mono.ttf');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }



  * {
      font-family: 'MonumentGrotesk-Mono' !important;
    }
```