# Which font file tyoe needed for Ionic apps

Tags: css, ionic-framework, fonts, font-face

In develop websites, we use several font file type such as: **.ttf**, **.svg**, **.woff**, **.woff2** and ... in `@font-face` because of the variety of browsers.

Now, Which font file type needed for Ionic apps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37771775/4711865

Comment: and dude, seriously... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @odedta it doesn't look like you clicked "close" with your SO posts as reason to close because the question is a duplicate. Rather than commenting on duplicate questions with a link, use that `close` option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic change default font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771723/ionic-change-default-font)

Comment: Hey @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't see any close option

Comment: ah my bad, close/reopen is at 3000, I thought it was 1500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In develop websites, we use several font file type such as: .ttf, .svg, .woff, .woff2 and ... in @font-face because of the variety of browsers.

No we do not.

In 2016, coming on to 2017, we don't need any of those formats except for WOFF/WOFF2, because some of those formats don't exist anymore (`eot`, `svg`), and some of them are not for the web but are universal system fonts with far stricter parsing rules (`ttf`, `otf`).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37091681/740553 for the more detailed explanation.