# How do I install new fonts in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Does anyone know how to update the font for Ionic 4?

I tried adding the aileron.woff to assets/fonts and putting this in the variables.scss to no avail.

```
  src: url('../assets/fonts/aileron.woff') format('woff');
```

Answer (score 90):

This is how I managed to add a custom font to my Ionic application

1. Add a directory that contains the font files to the project under the folder `src\assets\fonts`

   > ```
   > src\assets\fonts\myCustomFont
   >  |
   >  +-- MyCustomFontBold.ttf
   >  +-- MyCustomFontBoldItalic.ttf
   >  +-- MyCustomFontItalic.ttf
   >  +-- MyCustomFontRegular.ttf
   > ```
2. Define the fonts in the file `src\theme\variables.scss`:

   ```css
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'My Custom Font';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: normal;
     src: url('../assets/fonts/myCustomFont/MyCustomFontRegular.ttf');
   }

   @font-face {
     font-family: 'My Custom Font';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: bold;
     src: url('../assets/fonts/myCustomFont/MyCustomFontBold.ttf');
   }

   @font-face {
     font-family: 'My Custom Font';
     font-style: italic;
     font-weight: normal;
     src: url('../assets/fonts/myCustomFont/MyCustomFontItalic.ttf');
   }

   @font-face {
     font-family: 'My Custom Font';
     font-style: italic;
     font-weight: bold;
     src: url('../assets/fonts/myCustomFont/MyCustomFontBoldItalic.ttf');
   }
   ```
3. In the same file `src\theme\variables.scss`, edit the `:root` element to define your custom font as the font of the Ionic application:

   ```css
   --ion-font-family: 'My Custom Font';
   ```

Comment: You can fetch the font-face definitions from the web like https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed and copy the content from the url to variables.scss if you do not want to add the font files to the package

Comment: best and most complete answer I found on the internet

Comment: Works for Ionic 5 as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

1. Add a Custom Font in directory folder `src\assets\fonts`
2. Define the fonts in the file `src\theme\variables.scss` **before :root**

> @font-face {   font-family: "Custom Font";   src:
>   url("../assets/fonts/Custom Font.xxx"); }

3. define your custom font **in :root**

> --ion-font-family: "Custom Font";

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be interested in Ionic 4 / Angular.

I just created a test app with template "blank" in Ionic 4.0.0 beta. Here's what I put into variable.sccs to change all fonts across platforms:

```
:root,
:root[mode=ios],
:root[mode=md] {
  --ion-font-family: "Palatino", "Times New Roman", serif !important;

  font-family: "Palatino", "Times New Roman", serif !important;
}
```

On my Mac I see "Palatino".

The key is, to use "!important". As far as the Beta goes, theming of fonts is not yet documented. It may be clarified later or the behavior may change in final. Keep this in mind.

Answer (score 7):

Add your font in the directory `assets`, and add this to your `variables.scss` file to declare the font family and set a class that uses it:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'custom';
  src: url('../assets/fonts/custom.ttf');
}
.text-custom { 
  font-family: "custom"; 
}
```

Then in any `xx.page.html` you can use the class like this:

```
<span class="text-custom">your text</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: It's Work for me]

> It's work for me

*Make sure you give the current font folder path and file name*

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the CSS4 variable [--ion-font-family](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/css/typography.scss#L34)

Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test Font Family</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.2/dist/ionic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.2/css/ionic.min.css">
  <style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Hanalei Fill';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Hanalei Fill'), local('HanaleiFill-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/hanaleifill/v6/fC1mPYtObGbfyQznIaQzPQi8UAjA.woff2) format('woff2');
  }

  :root {
    --ion-font-family: 'Hanalei Fill';
  }
  :root[mode=md] {
    --ion-font-family: 'Hanalei Fill';
  }
  :root[mode=ios] {
    --ion-font-family: 'Hanalei Fill';
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ion-app>
    <ion-header translucent>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Test</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content id="content" fullscreen>
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-title>Font Family</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
          Testing
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What would I paste into the variables.scss? When I try the portion within the style selectors, I get this error. Refused to load the font 'data:application/font-woff;base64,  it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

1.Include the font ttf file inside the src/assets/fonts/ folder.

2.Now create the font family by including it in the global.scss(src/global.scss)
    EX:`@font-face {
      font-family: 'CustomfontName';
      src: url('./assets/fonts/CustomFont.ttf');
    }`

3.Apply the style

```
<ion-content>
  <div style='font-family:CustomfontName'>
      Sample text for custom font
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

**For better understanding click the below link,**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hz7SLdGG8HA

Answer (score 0):

in global.scss file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'quicksand';    //This is what we are going to call
  src: url('./assets/font/Quicksand-Bold_df5ccd3628ec30ca750b7a6c1f1d6dac.ttf');
}

.mobile-heading {
  font-family: "quicksand";
}
```

and in HTML file mobile-heading class

```
<h1 class="mobile-heading">quicksand Font apply</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

**look for the font that you like the most in:** https://fonts.google.com/

- Download the file `.woff2`    Example: `lato_font.woff2`
- Create a new folder in the assets directory `assets/fonts`
- In the folder `/fonts` add the file `lato_font.woff2`

**Then look in the themes folder for a .scss file: `theme/Variables.scss`**

Add before line `root: {  }`

Example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/lato_font.woff2') format('woff2');
}

.......

root:{
---  --- 
}
```

---

Add inside the `root: {}`

```
root: { 

--ion-font-family: "'Lato', sans-serif;"; }
```